# PrimeReact DataTable cell editing no working correctly with async calls

Tags: primereact

am facing this problem when i try to update a cell in the data table , the value is not updated imedietly (visual update) , the new value is shown when i click on another cell , here is part of updating code:

```
const onCellEditComplete = async (e) => {
let { rowData, column, newValue, field, originalEvent: event } = e;
//check if the new value is valid
if (isPositiveInteger(newValue) && newValue.toString().length > 0) {
let { error } = await productService.addPriceItem(
rowData["id" + field],
rowData.idItem,
column.key.substring(4),
newValue
);

if (error) {
showError(error.message);
event.preventDefault();
} else {
rowData[field] = newValue;  //update the value
}
} else event.preventDefault(); //cancel update for invalid values
};
```

the column code is shown bellow:

```
 <Column
                key={idTarif}
                field={field}
                header={header}
                style={{ minWidth: "100px" }}
                headerClassName="pi pi-calendar-plus"
                body={priceBodyTemplate}
                editor={(options) => cellEditor(options)}
                onCellEditComplete={onCellEditComplete}
              />
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the typed value immediately, you need to call the `options.editorCallback` function in the `InputText` `onChange` event. This updates the `options.value` and renders the updated value.

Please refer to the below code:

```js
const cellEditor = (options) => {
    return <InputText type="text" value={options.value} onChange={(e) => options.editorCallback(e.target.value)} />;
}
```